# Can we terminate openstack instance with Vagrant

Tags: vagrant, openstack, vagrantfile

Is there any method to terminate openstack instance using Vagrant-OpenStack-Plugin ?  Then how can we do that ?

Comment: what do you mean *terminate* you should be able to run vagrant halt/suspend to stop the instance or destroy to destroy the VM

Answer (score 0):

`vagrant destroy` terminates created instances.